# Problem : "String subscript out of range" C++

Tags: c++, string

Please help me debug this code. It gives me an error "String subscript out of range"

I can't  figure out why. The program needs to find numbers of substring in a string.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s1;
    string s2;
    int count = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "String : ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Substring : ";
    getline(cin, s2);
    int len = s2.length();
    while (s1[n] != ' ') {
        if (s1[n] == s2[m]) {
            while (s1[n] == s2[m] && s1[n] != '\0') {
                n++;
                m++;
            }
            if (m == len && (s1[n] == ' ' || s1[n] == '\0' )) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        else {
            while (s1[n] != ' ') {
                n++;
                if (s1[n] != '\0') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        n++;
        m = 0;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        cout << "String contains no subtring ! ";
    }
    else if (count > 0) {
        cout << "String contains " << count << " substring ! ";
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Have you run the program in a debugger? It should tell you exactly where this happens and what the program state is at the time.

Comment: What part of `"String subscript out of range"` is unclear to you? It means you are going out of bounds on one of your strings.  You should run your code though a debugger and see exactly where your indexes are not what you are expecting. But, I can already tell you that `while (s1[n] != ' ') { ... n++; }` is the wrong way to index through a `std::string`. And I can see quite a few places in your loops where out of bounds accesses are possible. Are you aware that `std::string` has a [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method for searching for a substring?

Comment: Looks like you allow `n` to grow longer than the length of the string.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. The error appears after I enter my input, I can't find a solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I aware that std::string has find() method but I want to count the substring without the find(), I just want to understand it clearly. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah I know that but I don't know how to solve that error. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could compare `n` to the length of the string and exit out of the loops when it is greater than or equal to the lenght. You could rewrite the code to use a range based for loop and get rid of `n` completely.  You could replace the code making better use of the standard library functionality for searching.

Comment: @drescherjm Good idea, I will try it. Thanks a lot. But I want to do the searching without the function to understand clearly. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Noob what EXACTLY is the code supposed to be doing in the first place? What is the GOAL here? It *looks* like you are trying to count the number of times a substring `s2` appears inside of `s1`, is that right?

Comment: If you use `at` instead of `[]` to index, you'll get some out of range protection.  Replace `s1[n]` with `s1.at(n)` and likewise with the rest of the code.  It'll still fault, but now it will fault with an exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I want to count how many times ```s2``` appear inside ```s1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping through the strings correctly, so you end up going out of bounds, causing undefined behavior.  You should not be using character values to know when you have reached the end of a string, use indexes instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1, s2;

    do {
        cout << "String : ";
        getline(cin, s1);
    }
    while (s1.empty());

    do {
        cout << "Substring : ";
        getline(cin, s2);
    }
    while (s2.empty());

    string::size_type s1_size = s1.size(),
                      s2_size = s2.size(),
                      m = 0,
                      n = 0,
                      k;
    int count = 0;

    while (n < s1_size) {
        if (s1[n] == s2[m]) {
            k = n;
            do {
                ++n;
                ++m;
            }
            while (n < s1_size && m < s2_size && s1[n] == s2[m]);
            if (m == s2_size) {
                ++count;
            }
            else {
                n = k + 1;
            }
            m = 0;
        }
        else {
            ++n;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        cout << "String contains no substring!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "String contains substring " << count << " time(s)!";
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HpzzMF)

Which can be greatly simplified if you use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1, s2;

    cout << "String : ";
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << "Substring : ";
    getline(cin, s2);

    string::size_type pos = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while ((pos = s1.find(s2, pos)) != string::npos) {
        ++count;
        pos += s2.size();
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        cout << "String contains no substring!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "String contains substring " << count << " time(s)!";
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/u5w1Ty)

Comment: I really appreciate it ! Thanks a lot